# dynamic allocation and polymorphism - c++

Tags: c++

Need some insight on how to complete this last part of my Marina class. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is a big project I'm working on. I created a group of classes that are derived from a base class Boat using public inheritance. The Marina class represents the care of the boats in a Marina. The Marina class contains a fixed size array of pointers to Boat.

The function should place a new Boat into the Marina if there is room and each new boat must be dynamically allocated. The function should also ask the user what kind of boat they want and then add that kind to the next empty place in the array.

Comment: There isn't sufficient info here to answer your question.

Comment: We need more information. How do you represent a Marina (is it a vector, a set, a record in a database, ...) ? Similarily how do you represent a boat ?

Comment: Your question is unclear, so I voted to close it. You should give much more code (at least the declaration of relevant classes) to get help.

Comment: It does not make it clearer. For example, without relevant class definition, "place a new Boat into the Marina" doesn't mean much.

Comment: There is not a single sentence ending in question mark in this post. "This line produces error" is not useful at all.

Comment: "How to do it?" - that's the only question you can ask at this moment? Please, be more specific.
And, do you have `Boat` class definition anywhere? Care to share?

Comment: If you don't have the Boat class definition, there is no way you can allocate memory for that, simply because you (or compiler) don't know how much to allocate.

Answer (score 1):

The error suggests that you forgot to include `Boat.h` (or anything defining class `Boat`) in your cpp file.

But anyway, code shown in question has some problems :

- line `_m[i] = NULL;` is outside of the loop where `i` is declared and will raise an error - and I cannot imagine a reason to have it there ...
- you create an uninitialized boat, and do not keep a pointer to it : how will you find and initialize it ?

You said that boats should be dynamically initialized, and that method `_add_boat` must be void. IMHO there are only two acceptable ways :

- create the boat outside of the method and only use `add_boat` to put it in marina (throwing exception if marina if full) :

  ```
  void Marina::_add_boat(Boat *boat)
  {
     for (unsigned i = 0; i < _num_boats; i++)
     {
        if (_m[i] == NULL)
           _m[i] = boat;
           return;
     }
     throw std::runtime_error("Marina full");
  }
  ```

  usage :

  ```
  Boat b = new Boat();
  marina._add_boat(b);
  ```
- pass arguments to initialize boat

  ```
  void Marina::_add_boat(int type, Owner& owner, ...) // arguments for Boat ctor
  {
     for (unsigned i = 0; i < _num_boats; i++)
     {
        if (_m[i] == NULL)
           _m[i] = new Boat(type, owner, ...);
           return;
     }
     throw std::runtime_error("Marina full");
  }
  ```

---

Below is original answer left only because some interesting comments refere to it

---

Why not something like :

I assume you have an array of boats (Boat *) in the Marina of size `_num_boats`. An empty place is conventionnaly a NULL. It gives :

```
static const unsigned int _num_boats = 100; // the value you need or a constexpr
class Marina {
    Boat * boats[_num_boats];
    ...

    Boat * Marina::_add_boat() {
        for (unsigned i=0; i<_num_boats; i++) {
            if (boats[i] == NULL) {
                boats[i] = new Boat();
                return boats[i]; // returns dynamically created Boat if room in Marina
            }
        }
        return NULL; // return NULL if Marina full
    }
}
```

With this logic you set attributes of Boat after placing it in Marina ...

Comment: This is not idomatic C++, I would suggest `std::vector<Boat>` or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Boat>>`

Comment: I must agree it is much like good old C ... But I did not use vector, because size is fixed and can be represented in a simple array, and did not use smart pointer either because I cannot figure if OP needs unique_ptr or shared_ptr ... And really wonder if this question deserved any answer because it will be hard to give a good one :-(

Comment: Use std::array for fixed sized arrays.

Comment: @sr19 hmmm... sounds like homework...;-/

Comment: @sr19: They are allowed, but you have to tell us what you need.  We can't follow rules you never told us.

Comment: @sr19 Questions about problems with homework are certainly allowed, but they are often problematic for many reasons. Being a homework question is no "excuse" for anything, question must still stand on its own. And "do my work for me" kind of questions are generally received badly, and with homework questions it's easy to fall for this.

Comment: Any reason to use `unsigned` type?

Comment: @n0rd : Really no reason - only because OP used it first and I just tried to keep close to what he did.